# On proving that $\sin x > x \cos x$ in a right neighbourhood of zero.

Tags: real-analysis

I was recently asked to prove rigorously that there exists a $\delta$ s.t. $\sin x > x \cos x$ in $]0,\delta[$ .

The best I could come up with was that Taylor expanding $\sin x - x  \cos x $ I obtain $\frac{ x^3}{3} + o(x^3)$ and noticing that the dominant term goes to zero for positive values I know that there must exist such a $\delta$.

But I was told this is not rigorous enough, how could I formalize it better? Any other paths I could take?

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus. If $f$ is continuously differentiable, then $f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t)\,dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Mean Value Theorem: for $x\in\mathbb{R}^*$, the function $\sin$ is continuous on $[0,x]$ and differentiable on $(0,x)$, hence there exists $c\in(0,x)$ such that
$$\sin(x)=x\cos(c).$$
Now, in the particular case where $x\in(0,\pi)$, we'll have $0<c<x<\pi$, and since $\cos$ is decreasing on $[0,\pi]$ we'll have
$$\cos(c)>\cos(x),$$
hence (since $x>0$),
$$x\cos(c)>x\cos(x).$$
We conclude that
$$\forall x\in(0,\pi),\ \sin(x)>x\cos(x).$$
Since $(0,\pi)$ is a punctured right sided neighborhood of $0$, we're done.

Comment: Thank you, just a question: why is $\cos(c)>\cos(x),$ $\forall x \in (0, \pi)$ if $c$ can be less than some $x$?

Comment: @Monolite: you have $0<c<x<\pi$; now $\cos$ is a decreasing function on $(0,\pi)$: hence $1>\cos(c)>\cos(x)>-1$. Note that the $c$ here _depends_ on $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate both functions. If derivative is greater than $0$ you are done the reason is at $x=0$ you have the equality $\sin(0)=0\cos(0)$. Derivative is
\begin{equation}
\cos(x)-\cos(x)-x(-\sin(x))>0.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

$${\sin x\over x}=\int_0^1\cos(t\,x)\>dt>\cos x\qquad(0<|x|\leq\pi)\ .$$

Comment: OP asks for strict inequality. MVT would be more appropriate, I guess.